# How to simplify below code by avoiding nesting in python?

Tags: python

I am looking for a simplified way of the below solution.

This is what I plan to do here:

- Iterate over the files in a folder
- find file matching pattern
- split filename
- find its corresponding new file
- if not found then delete the original file

---

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('folder'):
    for old_file in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(old_file, 'pattern'):
            spl = old_file.rsplit('_')
            new_file = os.path.isfile(f'folder/xxx_{int(spl[6])*2}_{int(spl[7])*2}_yyy.txt')
            if not new_file:
                # delete old_file
```

Comment: This may be a better candidate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You might be able to combine a couple of lines with ```pathlib.Path(...).glob(...)```.

Comment: Instead of `if fnmatch.fnmatch(old_file, 'pattern'): do thing` do `if not fnmatch.fnmatch(old_file, 'pattern'): continue` so you can unindent `do thing`.  Identify places where you can break out of the current control flow and you can reduce a lot of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the continue statement with the reversed conditions to progress towards deleting old files without nesting the conditions:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('folder'):
    for old_file in files:
        if not fnmatch.fnmatch(old_file, 'pattern'): continue
        spl = old_file.rsplit('_')
        new_file = os.path.isfile(f'folder/xxx_{int(spl[6])*2}_{int(spl[7])*2}_yyy.txt')
        if new_file: continue
        # delete old_file
```